Issue listing 'folders' in Swift Supabase Storage
I would like to access a list of folders at some path.
main

subfolder1


file1




file2


subfolder2


file1




file2




file3



let result = try await supabaseClient.storage
             .from(bucket_name)
             .list(path: "main/subfolder2")
When I request .list(path: "main/subfolder2") it's fine. It returns list of files in subfolder1.

let result = try await supabaseClient.storage
             .from(bucket_name)
             .list(path: "main")

However when I request .list("main") Swift responds with this:

valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Cannot get unkeyed decoding container -- found null value instead", underlyingError: nil))

It appears as if it is an issue with Swift Supabase library, but I am not sure.
In contrary to files, folders return null as id and it messes with Swift somehow, as other Supabase libraries seem to accept this state. How to circumvent this issue?

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code . Show also the full error message and on which line of the code it appears.
